# Android - Calculate Speed (Nmea String to get Speed)

Tags: java, android

I am interested to find out is there any way that I can get speed using Nmea String? Never heard of this before , please enlighten me. Thank you :) I'm doing an android in which I have calculate all distance and time.

Comment: I'd never heard of it before your question, but about 20 seconds later I'd got to this page: http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#nmea

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :) However, I am interested to know whether is it advisable to use this method or any another good method to get current speed when driving?

Comment: location.getSpeed() is much faster, and it returns the same value.

Answer (score 2):

NMEA is a text-based protocol used to communicate with GPS. It has several speed parameters, you need to check which are sent by your device: http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/

To get NMEA data on Android, simply enable the GPS provider and then register the NMEA listener with `[addNmeaListener(..)`][1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addNmeaListener%28android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener%29).

Then you need to parse the string parameter for the NMEA commands you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [LocationManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addNmeaListener%28android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener%29) and [Location.getSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed%28%29)

The best place to start is by reading the [developer guide for location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)